# Is it safe to fetch secure credentials in Travis CI in an open-source repo?

Tags: travis-ci

My open-source app uses AWS's Parameter Store feature to keep secure copies of app secrets (database passwords, etc). When my app is deployed to EC2 a script fetches these secrets and makes them available to the code, and I run this same script locally too.

Some of my tests need database access to run and therefore I need my Travis build script to have access.

Is it safe for me to run that script on my (public) Travis build? As far as I can tell, Travis doesn't expose the build artefacts anywhere (beyond what's on GitHub, which doesn't have my secrets). I know I can encrypt config items in my `.travis.yml` file but ideally there'd be a single place where this data lives, then I can rotate config keys without updating them in multiple places.

Is there a safe/better way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

If you're accepting pull requests, it's trivially easy to create a pull request that dumps the publicly dumps the keys to the Travis console. Since there's no restrictions on what PRs can modify, edit, etc., wherever the keys are, someone could easily modify the code & print them.

Travis built it [secure environment variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml) to prevent this type of attack, i.e. by not exposing the variables to PRs. That means that tests requiring secure environment variables can't be run with encrypted variables, but that's a trade off that one has to make.

Comment: Great point, completely forgot about the PR side of things. Will keep playing with the secure environment variables then.

Comment: so am I right in understanding that if I use "travis encrypt MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret --add env.matrix" like they do in that article you linked to. It's safe to store this in my public github and nobody can decrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

As StephenG has mentioned it is trivial to expose a secret as it is simply an environment variable that the CI systems try to mask.

Example with Bash:

```
$ SECRET=mysecret
$ rev <<< $SECRET
tercesym
```

Since the secret is now longer a perfect string match TravisCI, Jenkins, GitHub Actions will not be able to mask you secret anymore and let it be displayed on the console. There are other ways such as uploading a secret to an external server, and so on. For example one could just do `env >> debug.log` and if that `debug.log` file is archived, then the secret would be in that file.

Rather than connecting to your real backends, which is not a good idea for CI pipelines anyways, I would much rather recommend that you use a service container.

We do not use TravisCI so I don't how practical it is with Travis, but with Jenkins on Kubernetes and GitHub Actions you can add a service container that runs parallel to your tests.

For example if your integration tests need DB access to mysql or PSQL just run the containers for them. For dynamoDB Amazon provides a container implementation for the explicit purpose of testing your code against the DynamoDB API. If you need more AWS services, [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) offers fake AWS core services such as S3.

Now if you actually need to write data to your DBs in AWS ... you should probably expose that data as build artifacts and trigger a notification event instead so that a custom backend on your side can fetch the data on the trigger. Something like a small Lambda function for example.

Comment: Thank you! In the end, I realised that connecting to a real database from tests was an anti-pattern, and rewrote the tests to use a local database (eg. SQLite) so Travis didn't need to access any external dependencies, and to avoid encrypting secrets like this.